# Android App and Site shows different points

Tags: support, bug, android-app

SE mobile app shows wrong tag points whereas mobile and desktop site shows correct points.

**SE app for android**

[image]

Javascript tag have 79 points (wrong)

**SE site**

[image]

Javascript tag have 92 points (correct and Full site also produce the same)

**Update :**

I tried clearing cache, but no use.

I installed this app 3 or 4 days but I am holding 92 points in Javascript for more than a week.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is surely due to the cache.

If you are deleting your mobile device's *cached data*, you can able to see the latest tag points in the app.

Cached data in the path: `Settings -> Storage -> Cached data`

Comment: Tried. But no use. I installed this app recently(3/4 days) and I am holding 92 pts in JS for more than a weak.