# Is it possible to collect data from SE users to understand their usage of the site?

Tags: feature-request, support, users, research

I wonder if SE supports conducting research by allowing the collection of some data from its users. For example, I want to investigate what characteristics of users determine their behaviors in SE (e.g., type of questions they ask, their badges, etc.).

I wonder what would be a reasonable approach to conduct such research?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wonder what would be a reasonable approach to conduct such research?

Contact the Stack Exchange team via the [Contact Us form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) (linked in the footer) and explain your research objectives.

You may be required to sign an NDA if they agree to provide you with any non public information.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Also, I am interested in administrating a survey to collect user data about a different variable ? Is there a way to make this happen?

Comment: @Oded, did anyone noticed this issue? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292298/android-app-and-site-shows-different-points it is really confusing. I am asking because this q didn't get enough attention.

Comment: @SagarV - I am sure our mobile team has seen it. I don't do mobile dev.